# Unable to import own Framework in Xcode 7 Beta 3

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa, frameworks

I'm currently facing a problem trying to import my iOS Cocoa Touch Framework (written in Swift, built with Xcode 7 beta 3) inside of an application also written in Swift and built with the same version of Xcode.

I added the Framework to both "Embedded Binaries" and "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" in the General tab, added the path of the folder it is located in to "Framework Search Paths" in the Build Settings tab and to "Link Binary With Libraries" and "Embedded Frameworks" (with Destination set to "Frameworks") in the Build Phases tab. But for some reason, I'm not able to import the module inside of the project. It started off saying "No such module 'SwiftQLite'", now it says "Cannot load underlying module for 'SwiftQLite'". I had it working before, but now it's just throwing errors at me.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong? I added a few screenshots to this question to illustrate the problem.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE:**
I just found out that I can import and use the module in Objective-C, but only a part of all the functions is available in Objective-C. Importing in Swift doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT 08/11/2015: This has been fixed in Xcode Version 7.0 beta 5 (7A176x). I'm able to use my own frameworks in any project after importing them as Embedded Libraries.**

<strike>I'm having the same issue than nguoy_tk:</strike>

1. I built my framework with Xcode 7.0 Beta 3
2. I imported the framework in a new project built with Xcode 7 Beta 3 ( both "Embedded Binaries" and "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" )
3. Xcode would not find the module

However I just downloaded Xcode 7 beta 4, and while this issue seems to be gone, another one appeared when trying to import the module:

```
Cannot load underlying module for '[Module]'"
```

However the strange thing is that the build is successful.

[image]

Comment: I also have this issue. Xcode builds project successfully, but when I try to use classes from my framework I get strange errors: `2015-08-02 13:13:04.214 GeomProcessor[1513:423945] Could not find image named 'GenericPostscriptPrinter'.
2015-08-02 13:13:04.219 GeomProcessor[1513:423945] Failed to connect (_appIconImage) outlet from (PMPrintWindowController) to (NSImageView): missing setter or instance variable
2015-08-02 13:13:04.219 GeomProcessor[1513:423945] Failed to connect (_simplePrintView) outlet from (PMPrintWindowController) to (NSView): missing setter or instance variable`